# remove xml node using conditoning in xslt

Tags: xslt

I have xml like this ,

ex 1.

```
<books>
     <book type="ABA"></book>
     <book type="ABC"></book>
</books>
```

ex 2 .

```
<books>
 <book type="ABA"</book>
</books>
```

if ABA alone is there in the xml i want to delete the entire Books node. if along with aba other values are there i want to delete only book which is having that ABA value , so result xml will have ABC alone inside books.

```
<books>
 <book type="ABC"></book>
</books>
```

for ex 2 . books node should not come.please assist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="book[@type='ABA']"/>

<xsl:template match="books[not(book[not(@type='ABA')])]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: XSL also need to check whether the Books node is there or not , if its not there then no need to check that xml itself

Comment: @Abi I don't understand your comment. If `books` is not there, then the template matching it will never be instantiated.

Comment: Sorry mike , i handled that XQuery ... Sorry for the confusion